# Remover Registros Duplicados em apenas uma coluna de um data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

tudo bem ?

Estou com uma duvida relacionada a Pandas no Python e após muito quebrar a cabeça, não cheguei a uma conclusão do que posso fazer.

Após alguns cruzamentos eu fico com um produto cartesiano repetindo as chamadas para cada data do meu DF, oque faz o meu volume de informações se repetir varias vezes na coluna.

Deixo a baixo uma amostra de 12 linhas deste DataFrame;

```
 import pandas as pd 

carteira = [ 'BRASILIA - GERAL','Cosern - Telecobranca',
            'Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria','Elektro - Geral',
            'BRASILIA - GERAL','Cosern - Telecobranca','Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria',
            'Elektro - Geral','BRASILIA - GERAL','Cosern - Telecobranca',
            'Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria','Elektro - Geral' ]

data = ['25/03/2022','25/03/2022','25/03/2022','25/03/2022','25/03/2022','25/03/2022',
        '25/03/2022','25/03/2022','25/03/2022','25/03/2022','25/03/2022','25/03/2022'] 

agente = [3587, 3587, 3587, 3587, 5348, 5348, 5348, 5348, 5349, 5349, 5349,5349]

operador = ['Bruna', 'Bruna', 'Bruna', 'Bruna','Ana','Ana','Ana','Ana', 'Edneia','Edneia','Edneia','Edneia'] 

acordo = [3,4,10,7,3,7,7,1,8,3,8,3 ] 

Chamadas_agente = [292,292,292,292,206,206,206,206,239,239,239,239] 



# obtenha a lista de tuplas de duas listas e mescle-as usando zip().
lista_de_tuplas = list(zip(carteira, data, agente, operador, acordo, Chamadas_agente))  

# Convertendo listas de tuplas em Dataframe do pandas.
df = pd.DataFrame(
    lista_de_tuplas,
    columns=['carteira', 'data','agente','operador','acordo','Chamadas_agente']
)

display(df)
```

```
                             carteira        data  agente operador  acordo  \
0                    BRASILIA - GERAL  25/03/2022    3587    Bruna       3   
1               Cosern - Telecobranca  25/03/2022    3587    Bruna       4   
2   Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria  25/03/2022    3587    Bruna      10   
3                     Elektro - Geral  25/03/2022    3587    Bruna       7   
4                    BRASILIA - GERAL  25/03/2022    5348      Ana       3   
5               Cosern - Telecobranca  25/03/2022    5348      Ana       7   
6   Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria  25/03/2022    5348      Ana       7   
7                     Elektro - Geral  25/03/2022    5348      Ana       1   
8                    BRASILIA - GERAL  25/03/2022    5349   Edneia       8   
9               Cosern - Telecobranca  25/03/2022    5349   Edneia       3   
10  Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria  25/03/2022    5349   Edneia       8   
11                    Elektro - Geral  25/03/2022    5349   Edneia       3   

    Chamadas_agente  
0               292  
1               292  
2               292  
3               292  
4               206  
5               206  
6               206  
7               206  
8               239  
9               239  
10              239  
11              239  
​
```

Devido a coluna carteira não estar não ter relação com as outras informações, o campo Chamadas_agente acaba repetindo o valor diversas vezes por data.

Para uma solução rápida e que me atenderia, eu pendei em apagar os registros duplicados da coluna Chamadas_agente, mantendo apenas um registro por data.

o retorno final seria mais ou menos assim como a a baixo, mantendo apenas uma chamada por dia.
de alguma forma eu consigo fazer isso

```
 carteira        data  agente operador  acordo  \
0                    BRASILIA - GERAL  25/03/2022    3587    Bruna       3   
1               Cosern - Telecobranca  25/03/2022    3587    Bruna       4   
2   Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria  25/03/2022    3587    Bruna      10   
3                     Elektro - Geral  25/03/2022    3587    Bruna       7   
4                    BRASILIA - GERAL  25/03/2022    5348      Ana       3   
5               Cosern - Telecobranca  25/03/2022    5348      Ana       7   
6   Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria  25/03/2022    5348      Ana       7   
7                     Elektro - Geral  25/03/2022    5348      Ana       1   
8                    BRASILIA - GERAL  25/03/2022    5349   Edneia       8   
9               Cosern - Telecobranca  25/03/2022    5349   Edneia       3   
10  Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria  25/03/2022    5349   Edneia       8   
11                    Elektro - Geral  25/03/2022    5349   Edneia       3   

    Chamadas_agente  
0               292  
1                 
2                
3                 
4               206  
5                 
6                 
7                 
8               239  
9                 
10                
11
```

Comment: .drop_duplicates? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: @RenatoC.Francisco o df.drop_duplicates('Chamadas_agente') tiraria todos os campos duplicados e manteria apenas um registro de cada.
Neste caso deixaria apenas tres linhas... infelizmente nao funcionaria, não do jeito que eu gostaria, claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa seria agrupar por agente, gerar um rank desse agente e filtar pelo rank 1:

```
df['Chamadas_agente'] = df['Chamadas_agente'][df.groupby('agente')['Chamadas_agente'].rank(method='first') == 1]
```

Mudando o tipo e preenchendo valores nulos

```
df['Chamadas_agente'] = df['Chamadas_agente'].fillna(-1).astype('int').astype('str').str.replace('-1', '')
```

Saída:

|  | carteira | data | agente | operador | acordo | Chamadas_agente |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | BRASILIA - GERAL | 25/03/2022 | 3587 | Bruna | 3 | 292 |
| 1 | Cosern - Telecobranca | 25/03/2022 | 3587 | Bruna | 4 |  |
| 2 | Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria | 25/03/2022 | 3587 | Bruna | 10 |  |
| 3 | Elektro - Geral | 25/03/2022 | 3587 | Bruna | 7 |  |
| 4 | BRASILIA - GERAL | 25/03/2022 | 5348 | Ana | 3 | 206 |
| 5 | Cosern - Telecobranca | 25/03/2022 | 5348 | Ana | 7 |  |
| 6 | Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria | 25/03/2022 | 5348 | Ana | 7 |  |
| 7 | Elektro - Geral | 25/03/2022 | 5348 | Ana | 1 |  |
| 8 | BRASILIA - GERAL | 25/03/2022 | 5349 | Edneia | 8 | 239 |
| 9 | Cosern - Telecobranca | 25/03/2022 | 5349 | Edneia | 3 |  |
| 10 | Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria | 25/03/2022 | 5349 | Edneia | 8 |  |
| 11 | Elektro - Geral | 25/03/2022 | 5349 | Edneia | 3 |  |

---

Caso queira agrupar por data basta adicionar ao groupby:

```
df['Chamadas_agente'] = df['Chamadas_agente'][df.groupby(['agente','data'])['Chamadas_agente'].rank(method='first') == 1]

df['Chamadas_agente'] = df['Chamadas_agente'].fillna(-1).astype('int').astype('str').str.replace('-1', '')
```

Saída:

|  | carteira | data | agente | operador | acordo | Chamadas_agente |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | BRASILIA - GERAL | 25/03/2022 | 3587 | Bruna | 3 | 292 |
| 1 | Cosern - Telecobranca | 25/03/2022 | 3587 | Bruna | 4 |  |
| 2 | Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria | 25/03/2022 | 3587 | Bruna | 10 |  |
| 3 | Elektro - Geral | 25/03/2022 | 3587 | Bruna | 7 |  |
| 4 | BRASILIA - GERAL | 25/03/2022 | 5348 | Ana | 3 | 206 |
| 5 | Cosern - Telecobranca | 25/03/2022 | 5348 | Ana | 7 |  |
| 6 | Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria | 25/03/2022 | 5348 | Ana | 7 |  |
| 7 | Elektro - Geral | 25/03/2022 | 5348 | Ana | 1 |  |
| 8 | BRASILIA - GERAL | 25/03/2022 | 5349 | Edneia | 8 | 239 |
| 9 | Cosern - Telecobranca | 25/03/2022 | 5349 | Edneia | 3 |  |
| 10 | Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria | 25/03/2022 | 5349 | Edneia | 8 |  |
| 11 | Elektro - Geral | 25/03/2022 | 5349 | Edneia | 3 |  |
| 12 | BRASILIA - GERAL | 26/03/2022 | 3587 | Bruna | 3 | 292 |
| 13 | Cosern - Telecobranca | 26/03/2022 | 3587 | Bruna | 4 |  |
| 14 | Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria | 26/03/2022 | 3587 | Bruna | 10 |  |
| 15 | Elektro - Geral | 26/03/2022 | 3587 | Bruna | 7 |  |
| 16 | BRASILIA - GERAL | 26/03/2022 | 5348 | Ana | 3 | 206 |
| 17 | Cosern - Telecobranca | 26/03/2022 | 5348 | Ana | 7 |  |
| 18 | Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria | 26/03/2022 | 5348 | Ana | 7 |  |
| 19 | Elektro - Geral | 26/03/2022 | 5348 | Ana | 1 |  |
| 20 | BRASILIA - GERAL | 26/03/2022 | 5349 | Edneia | 8 | 239 |
| 21 | Cosern - Telecobranca | 26/03/2022 | 5349 | Edneia | 3 |  |
| 22 | Cosern - Telecobranca Obrigatoria | 26/03/2022 | 5349 | Edneia | 8 |  |
| 23 | Elektro - Geral | 26/03/2022 | 5349 | Edneia | 3 |  |

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda !
Funcionou perfeitamente a solução, tanto eu quanto a minha equipe ficamos pensando em formas de resolver o dia todo, mas nao temos todo o conhecimento pra isso ainda.
Essa sua resposta abriu outros horizontes, relacionados a outros relatórios.
Agradeço por mim e pela galera aqui do setor que acompanhou sua resposta comigo !

Comment: @DiogenesCosta, por nada! Que bom que pude contribuir para ajudar você e sua equipe, fico feliz que tenha conseguido resolver o problema. Precisando estamos ai! Grande abraço!